# Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D Trying to convert a canvas into image

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am having an issue creating an image of a canvas and translating it onto another canvas. The end goal is to create a loupe magnifier for a cgm viewer/editor, but I'm stuck on this issue. Here is an example.

```
HTML: 

<canvas id="canvas" width=240 height=240 style="background-color: aqua; 
left:0;right:0;margin:auto;z-index:1;margin-top:0px;">
</canvas>
<canvas id="canvas1" width=240 height=240 style="background-color:#808080;">
</canvas>
<p></p>
<a id="download"  href="" onclick="draw_image();">Download to myImage.jpg</a>

JS:

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ox = canvas.width / 2;
var oy = canvas.height / 2;
ctx.font = "42px serif";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
ctx.fillStyle = "#800";
ctx.fillRect(ox / 2, oy / 2, ox, oy);

draw_image = function() {
let canvas1 = document.getElementById('canvas1') 
var image = canvas1.toDataURL("image/png")
let ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");


ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted to just draw a canvas, no some url
And you wanted to type `ctx1` and not `ctx`

```
draw_image = function() {
  let canvas1 = document.getElementById('canvas1') 
  let ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");

  // just draw the original canvas
  ctx1.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0)
};
```

Comment: Sorry you are right I meant ctx1.drawImage() but it doesnt let me just put the context of the canvas in the other canvas it throws an 404 error on jsfiddle and on my project nothing happens.

Comment: @MatthewWithington that's because you are using an `a` tag instead of `button` and your page reloads.

Do you want to download the image or to draw it on another canvas? Because these are separate things.